# XNA Platformer - Where should tile collision handling be?

Tags: c#, collision-detection, xna-4.0, tilemap, platformer

I've started using XNA and am working on a simple 2D platformer (single level). However, I am stuck as to where the collision detection should be handled. Here is my current project structure:

- The level is a child class of `GameScene` which is a base class for different screens (menus and such)
- The game is based off of a structure where everything is tile-based

  - Therefore, everything inherits from `Tile` which in turn inherites from `DrawableGameComponent`

Currently I have a character (`Character`) and a block tile (`Block`), but there will be different other tiles as well. There are several types of blocks that the player cannot walk through, and should stop moving (in the necessary dimension) upon collision.

I know how to detect collisions; my problem is determining where the Collision detection code should go for player movement. I was told that all collisions should be handled by a separate collision manager which would be passed the (list) of objects to check and then resolve all collisions.

However, the way I was implementing this was to check for collisions, and if they occurred, I would have to check on which side the collision occurred, and then backtrack the character to a position directly flanking the other tile. Here is a (very brief - not all code) example:

#### Character_Block_CollisionManager.cs

```
public class Character_Block_CollisionManager : GameComponent
{
    private Character character;
    private List<Block> tileList;

    public Character_Block_CollisionManager(Game game, Character character, List<Tile> tileList)
        : base(game)
    {
        this.character = character;
        this.tileList = tileList;
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //Checks for collisions and updates the objects accordingly
        foreach (Tile tile in tileList)
        {
            //Get intersection bounds of character and current tile
            Rectangle characterBounds = character.CollisionBounds;
            Rectangle tileBounds = tile.CollisionBounds;

            //Get horizontal and vertical differences in position between character and current tile
            float xDiff = characterBounds.X - tileBounds.X;
            float yDiff = characterBounds.Y - tileBounds.Y;

            //Track the post-collision location of the character (character cannot be displayed inside a wall)
            Vector2 postCollisionLocation = character.Position;

            //Check for a collision
            if (tileBounds.Intersects(characterBounds))
            {
                //Find the intersection rectangle between the two tiles
                Rectangle intersectionRectangle = Rectangle.Intersect(tileBounds, characterBounds);

                if (intersectionRectangle.Width > intersectionRectangle.Height)
                {
                    //A collision has occurred on either the top or bottom of the current tile
                    if (character.Position.Y + characterBounds.Height / 2 > tile.Position.Y + tileBounds.Height / 2)
                    {
                        //A collision has occurred on the bottom of the current tile
                        postCollisionLocation = new Vector2(character.Position.X, tileBounds.Y + tileBounds.Height + characterBounds.Height / 2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //A collision has occurred on the top of the current tile
                        postCollisionLocation = new Vector2(character.Position.X, tileBounds.Y - characterBounds.Height / 2);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //A collision has occurred on either the left or right of the current tile
                    if (character.Position.X + characterBounds.Width / 2 > tile.Position.X + tileBounds.Width / 2)
                    {
                        //A collision has occurred on the right of the current tile
                        postCollisionLocation = new Vector2(tileBounds.X + tileBounds.Width + characterBounds.Width / 2, character.Position.Y);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //A collision has occurred on the right of the current tile
                        postCollisionLocation = new Vector2(tileBounds.X - characterBounds.Width / 2, character.Position.Y);
                    }
                }

                //Update the position if the character to reflect the collision
                character.Position = postCollisionLocation;
            }
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
}
```

#### Level.cs

```
public class Level : GameScene
{
    private Tile[,] map = new Tile[32, 18];

    private Character character;
    private List<Tile>tileList;

    private CharacterCollisionManager characterCollisionManager;

    public Level1(Game game, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        : base(game, spriteBatch)
    {
        //Create character here...

        this.Components.Add(character);

        tileList = new List<Tile>();

        //Create blocks here...

        tileList.Add(block1);
        tileList.Add(block2);

        foreach (Tile tile in tileList)
        {
            this.Components.Add(tile);
        }

        characterCollisionManager = new CharacterCollisionManager(game, character, tileList);
        this.Components.Add(characterCollisionManager);
    }
}
```

This does work, but also means that I need to know which side the collision occurred on in order to reposition the character. One approach I have heard a lot about is the approach of creating a temporary player location based on movement and then checking said temporary location for collisions. If collisions will occur, calculate the distance to a collision on each axis and move the player that distance. Otherwise, proceed as normal.

This seems all very good in theory, but I am now stuck with the problem of not knowing where to implement this logic... Here are the possibilities I see:

- `Player` class

  - Here is where it seems to need to be in order to have access to player position and therefore be able to calculate a temporary position and check it for collisions (this would be in `Character` Update())
  - However, it wouldn't have access to any of the other tiles to check against, so this seems pointless
- `CollisionManager` class

  - Here is where it seems to need to be in order to have access to all the other tiles and calculate collisions.
  - **Clarifying Edit:** It seems that this will mean I can't create a tempory player position (based on input) and check it for collisions, as the position will have already been completely calculated in the `Player`  `Update` method, which will thus have already been moved (possibly into a collision situation).
    Rather than this, I want to test the temporary position for a collision and if one occurs, change the temporary position to the closest it can get without a collision. Finally, I would update the Player's position to be the temporary position. However, as I see it this can only be done from the `Player` class (as the collision manager does not have access to the `Player` `Update` method).

That's basically all I've been able to come up with, which doesn't seem like much. I'm sure other people have done similar things, but have not been able to find a tutorial in this manner. Trust me, I have looked (I wouldn't have posted otherwise). Other tutorials/questions will often have some necessary code/pseudocode, but I've not found one that tells me **where** to put the code and **why**. If someone could please do this for me I would greatly appreciate it!

Let me know if I should add anything else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely do this in the `CollisionManager` class. However, your question seems to allude to something inhibiting you from doing this, although I'm not sure what. If you're worried about good code design, then it's fine to use `Get` and `Set` methods to retrieve and set the positions you need when detecting and resolving collisions. This doesn't violate encapsulation.

A `CollisionManager` would also be extensible, meaning when you go to write other collision stuff, you can modify and generalise your `CollisionManager` rather than cluttering lots of other classes with collision logic. If you find an issue down the line with some collision code, it's much easier to change it once in the `CollisionManager` rather than lots of times in each individual class which implements collision detection/handling.

Edit: Ok, I see what you mean now. You're describing continuous collision detection. I had discrete collision detection in mind! I'm not used to this type of collision detection, so I'm not going to be of much help. I guess you could work the character's position at the next update based on current velocity, etc. and pass that to the `CollisionManager`, but I'm sure there are better ways of doing it.

You do have the option of using discrete collision detection, which is when you update the world, then check to see if anything has collided. If they have, you separate them, then render the scene. It's very easy to implement, and given that your game's a simple platformer, I can't see any major downsides to implementing it this way. It's up to you though!

Comment: Does the clarification I made help you to understand what I mean? A lot of people seem to recommend checking where the next position "would be" and then moving as close to it as possible. However, I can't do this from the `CollisionManager` as it doesn't have access to the `Player`'s `Update` method. Correct me if I'm wrong... Thanks!

Comment: @KendallRoth I understand what you mean. I've updated my answer.

Comment: So you're suggesting that I move the Player in the `Player` `Update` method, and then check for collisions in the `CollisionManager` class...if a collision occurs I then separate them so they appear to be touching??  Did I get that right?
If so I think I also see what you mean about making it extensible...you're suggesting that I use **one** `CollisionManager` to check/resolve collisions between non-moving (brick, door, etc)  and moving entities (player, enemy, etc), right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm suggesting. It's how I'd implement it anyway (and have done so in the past).

Comment: Final thing :). Say that a `MoveableTile` (character) falls onto a `Tile` (platform) and should play a noise. I'd use this `CollisionManager` to manage the post-collision positioning, but what about sound? I'd likely want another collision manager class for character specific collisions, right (for example)? And then in this other class not worry at all about positioning (covered in this `CollisionManager`), but only about other things (like sounds, animations, etc)??? Otherwise this `CollisionManager` would be filled with a **lot** of extra logic that would only happen for certain `Tiles`.

Comment: The observer design pattern is your friend here. Basically, you have several observers in your game. In this case, one of the observers is an `AudioManager`. When a collision occurs, the `CollisionManager` "announces" this collision; that is to say, it sends a message to all the observers to let them know that Object A collided with Object B. Then, the observers get this message and decide what to do. If the message says "Player landed on block", the audio manager will play the appropriate sound. This page has more info and an implementation: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/observer.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31932/discussion-between-kendall-roth-and-kevloughrey).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! It gives a good foothold into Collisions!